# android: which is better downloading the data and start the activity or

Tags: android, download, android-activity

Which is better to download the data in the current activity and then send the data to the second activity, or send the url to the second activity and there download the data.
thank you

edit:
I have two activity:
first activity have a list view, so when you click on one row it will take you to the second activity.
i want to show progress dialog when the app download the data, so i think to show the dialog at the first activity and then after the downloading finished i will start the second activity. actually i want to download the data in the first activity because i also want to download an ad to show to the user before the second activity start !

Comment: Second option sounds better

Comment: but why? i think in the first i could show progress downloading in the same activity and then go to the second activity, is there a reason why you prefer the #2

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking option 2 is better. But it depends on your situation. If you want the second activity to start only when the data is ready it might be better to download it in activity 1. You can send the data using the intent. The data needs to extend parcelable (meaning it can be written to disk and be parsed back) so it can add it as an extra to the intent. You can also keep the data in a static variable.

EDIT: If you want to download the data in activity 1 you should you an AsyncTask:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It will download the data in another thread so the UI thread is not interrupted. The AsyncTask provides a good way to update on your progress. When the user presses on a list item in activity 1, open a dialog with a progress bar and start the async task that downloads the data. When the async task is done and the data have been downloaded keep it in a static variable (This is the simplest way) and then use it in activity 2.

More on async tasks:
 http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

EDIT 2: Basically AsyncTasks have 4 main methods:
 onPreExecute() which is called on the UI thread. You can use it to start the dialog that will show the progress:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ShowDialog();
}
```

doInBackground() which is called on another thread, meaning that you can perform long operations on it. Download your data here. Use publishProgress() to publish your progress.

onProgressUpdate() which is called on the UI thread, meaning that you can communicate with UI staff like your dialog- so here you should update its progress:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {        
setDialogProgress(progress[0]);
}
```

onPostExecute() which is called on the UI thread. The data have been downloaded. Start activity 2. Keep the data in a static variable or send it with the intent to activity 2. Then get the data in activity 2 and show it.

That's it :)

Comment: actually i agree with you, so i choose method number one but there is a problem : if the user click on another button in the firs activity it will download  another data, so is there a way to prevent that. thank you

Comment: So you have activity one with few buttons and each button should open acticity two with a different data?

Comment: So it that case you have few options: 1. Each button will start activity 2 with a different url in the intent extras. Activity 2 will use that url to download the right data and show it. 2. Download all the data if its light in activity 1. Keep it in a static variable or send it with the intent to activity 2. This option will be faster for the user because activity two will show the data very soon but it will download unused data.

Comment: actually i think for another sol, maybe there is a way to inactive the the buttons if one button clicked.

Comment: Can you write what exactly you are trying ti do?